# multiprocess iterations missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

`multiprocess` seems to miss certain iterations. It looks like certain `hoy`s aren't being processed. But, the code also runs slower under `multiprocess`ing than it does in a single loop so maybe it's iterating multiple times? I've also never seen it go all the way to 8760.

I've run print statements at various points in the code to debug (can't step through a multiproces in VS Code). Here is an example of where hours are missing (columns: hoy, processor ID, start/end of `calc_hr`, hour gap):

```
    8394    13335   start   1
    8394    13335   end 0
    8395    13335   start   1
    8395    13335   end 0
    8451    13334   start   56
    8451    13334   end 0
    8452    13334   start   1
    8452    13334   end 0
```

You can see that the missing hours seem to be a problem between processes (i.e. 13335 13334)

```
CONTROLS = 'cont', 'multi', 'bi'

class ControlEnergy():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.energy = []

def make_control_energy():
    ctrls = []
    for name in CONTROLS:
        ctrls.append(ControlEnergy(name))
    return ctrls

def shade_cases_energy(hoy):
    ctrls = make_control_energy()
    for case in ('a', 'b'):
        for ctrl in ctrls:
            pass
    return ctrls

def calc_hour(hoy):
    print(','.join([str(hoy), str(getpid()), 'start']))

    if hoy > 6 and hoy < 15:
        ctrls = shade_cases_energy(hoy)
    else:
        ctrls = make_control_energy()
        for ctrl in ctrls:
            pass
    print(','.join([str(hoy), str(getpid()), 'start']))
    return ctrls

N_PROCESSES = 7
period = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if N_PROCESSES > 1:
        args = [[hoy] for hoy in range(8760)]
        with Pool(N_PROCESSES) as pool:
            period.extend(pool.starmap(calc_hour, args))
    else:
        for hoy in range(8760):
            period.extend(calc_hour(hoy))
```

I've used multiprocess.Pool a few times before and don't know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not missing any iterations. But `print` is not thread safe, so you are just not getting all the prints. If you add a newline to each string printed and add `end='', flush=True` to your `print`, you will see all of your iterations.

Comment: That’s exactly what it was. Thanks. Unfortunately I thought I’d found a clue to the bigger problem: multiprocess is slower than single loop. If I can’t figure that one out will post another question that hones in on that. Thanks again.

Comment: Your sample code runs so fast that there is no advantage to multiprocessing. Also, there is overhead in using multiprocessing, so the tasks that you submit must involve enough work to overcome that overhead, otherwise, multiprocessing will actually be slower.

Comment: To see the effects of multiprocessing, I added a `sleep(0.01)` to your `calc_hour()` method. For a pool of 7 processes, it took 12.934s to complete and with 1 process it took 1m29.293s.

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking. It might not be worth it, CPU is at 1% per process in my actual (not sample) code, but, the places where I’ve put pass, and other locations, are placeholders for pretty involved computations ...am also wondering about thread safety and my functions, classes, etc. and, what exactly gets copied to each process. Looks about 200MB per process.